# Resample sum keeping the index of last observation per day pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe:

```
Localmax              symbol  dvol        idx
2016-10-19 09:05:00   st1     5172.159  2016-10-19 09:05:00
2016-10-19 09:05:00   st2     5172.18   2016-10-19 09:05:00 
2016-10-19 17:30:00   st1     5000      2016-10-19 17:30:00
2016-10-19 17:40:00   st2     8000      2016-10-19 17:40:00
```

How can I do resample per symbol, so that I have a sum of dvol per day, KEEPING the index of the last observation per day?

I tried:

```
> df['idx']=df.index 
> dvol_sum = df.groupby(['symbol', Grouper(freq='D')])['dvol', 'idx'].agg(['sum'])
```

but it produced just one column of dvol, and the index with 00:00:00 time stamp..

The expected output is:

```
    Localmax         symbol         dvol              
2016-10-19 17:30:00   st1     sum of dvol for 2016-10-19 for st1 
2016-10-19 17:40:00   st2     sum of dvol for 2016-10-19 for st2
```

Comment: what's your desired output?

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `groupby` and `sum` on column symbol.
Then use `groupby` and `max` to select a index with latest entry of localmax:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Localmax':['2016-10-19 09:05:00','2016-10-19 09:05:00','2016-10-19 17:30:00','2016-10-19 17:40:00'],
               'symbol':['st1','st2','st1','st2'], 'dvol':[5172.159,5172.18,5000,8000]})


df['Localmax'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Localmax'])
df['date'] = df['Localmax'].dt.date

df_new = df.groupby(['symbol','date'])['dvol'].sum().reset_index()

df_new.index = df.groupby(['symbol','date'])['Localmax'].agg(max)

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
                   symbol       dvol
Localmax                             
2016-10-19 17:30:00    st1  10172.159
2016-10-19 17:40:00    st2  13172.180
```

Comment: should not I indicate Daily frequency of "resample" when creating df_new?

Comment: It does not give expected result if there are multiple dates.

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a simple way better than this but this works fine:

```
In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
              Localmax symbol      dvol                  idx
0  2016-10-19 09:05:00    st1  5172.159  2016-10-19 09:05:00
1  2016-10-19 09:05:00    st2  5172.180  2016-10-19 09:05:00
2  2016-10-19 17:30:00    st1  5000.000  2016-10-19 17:30:00
3  2016-10-19 17:40:00    st2  8000.000  2016-10-19 17:40:00
4  2016-10-20 17:30:00    st1  6000.000  2016-10-19 17:30:00
5  2016-10-20 17:40:00    st2  9000.000  2016-10-19 17:40:00

In [59]: df['Localmax'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Localmax'])

In [60]: df['date'] = df['Localmax'].dt.date

In [61]: new_df = df.groupby(['date','symbol'],as_index=False)['dvol'].max()

In [62]: new_df['date'] = new_df.date.map(df.groupby(['date'])['Localmax'].max())

In [63]: new_df
Out[63]: 
                 date symbol      dvol
0 2016-10-19 17:40:00    st1  5172.159
1 2016-10-19 17:40:00    st2  8000.000
2 2016-10-20 17:40:00    st1  6000.000
3 2016-10-20 17:40:00    st2  9000.000
```